# Stretch Function C++ Stack Based Implementation

Tags: c++, stack

I am working on a stack based implementation function that "stretches" the given input by a k value. For example for a string "abc" stretched by 2, the output would be `abc, aabc, abbc, abcc, aabbc, aabcc, abbcc, aabbcc`. So far the code I have is producing the output `cc bb aa` but I am not sure where my logic has an error that is causing this incorrect output.

My Code:

```
class Node
{
    public:
        string word; // stores the word in the node
        Node *next;
        Node(); //default constructor (never used)
        Node(string); // Constructor creates Node with word
        Node(string, int, int);
};

Node :: Node()
{
    word = "";
    next = NULL;
}

// Constructor with string input sets word and freq to 1
Node :: Node(string s)
{
    word = s;
    next = NULL;
}

class List
{
    public:
        Node *head; // Stores head of linked list
        List();
        string print();
}

List :: List()
{
    head = NULL;
}

string List :: print()
{
    Node *curr = head; // curr is ths current node as it progresses through the linked list. Initialized to head to start at the head of the list
    string output = ""; // output string
    while(curr!=NULL){ // loop over list
        output = output + " " + curr->word; //append current word onto output string
        curr = curr->next; // proceed to next node
    }
    return output;
}

List stretch(string input_str, int val) {
    List final_output;
    int length = input_str.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        string insert = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < val; j++) {
            insert.push_back(input_str[i]);
        }
        final_output.insert(insert);
    }
    return final_output;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    List myList2 = stretch("abc", 2);
    cout << "Stretch: " << myList2.print() << endl;
}
```

Comment: What are the results of your debugging session?  Please edit your question with the results as text.  For example, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the expected values of variables?  What are the actual values of variables?  What inputs did you supply to the program?

Comment: Your code provided above simply takes each character and makes it a string of supplied length( val param of stretch func) and adds to list. There is no logic written for the other expected combinations, you need to write it first :-)